# ceiling fan rotate slowly in my bedroom only

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I had one ceiling fan which was rotating slowly.I thought fan might have issues, so I shifted that fan to my shop.to my amazement, the same fan is working fantastic there. Then I bought a brand new ceiling fan of Khaitan & fixed in my bedroom but again it rotate slowly. I guess there must be some problem in my electric connection but again all other fan in my house are working fine ,only my bedroom fan rotate slowly.
  please friend I want your opinion.

Comment: Might there be a dimmer switch (or anything other than a regular switch) in the line?

Comment: check the volts overt he fan while it is working, is it is lower than you expect then it is in series with another lamp or something or there is a dimmer switch

Comment: How is the speed controlled?  Does it use a switch on the wall or a pull chain?  Did the fan ever work correctly (fast) for you?

Comment: ratchet freak is probably leading you in the right direction.  Check the voltage at the fan in the bedroom, my guess is it's underpowered.

Comment: how to check voltage ? And what is dimmer switch ? sorry guyes I don't know much about electric work.

Comment: hey dear auujay , speed is controlled by switch on the wall.

Comment: @JagdishPhadke, I would recommend that you call in an electrician to help diagnose this. Based on the fan brand, I'm assuming you're in India, and that you're working with 220VAC. If you don't even know how to check your voltage, let somebody trained to work with electricity do so.

Comment: Just to ask a stupid question: How are you switching the fan on and off -- via a wall switch, or via the pull chain? Most fans these days have multi-speed switches on the pull chain, so the solution might be to simply turn on the switch and pull the chain a few times until it cycles to the speed you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase a cheap volt meter (make sure it can measure AC) at any hardware or large general store.

At the ceiling fan electrical box you need to measure the voltage.

Here is [a good tutorial](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_3/9.html) to get you started.

Once you measure your voltage (depending on where in the world you are) check and see if it is close to what should be reaching your outlet/fan.

I am assuming you will find that it is lower, if you do at this point you are going to have to troubleshoot that circuit. There are a few ways to do this with different forms of technology but the cheapest by far is the old fashioned method of tracing the wiring.

If you can get into the attic or crawl space do your best to trace the physical circuit throughout your house. You want to see what other devices are on this circuit. Are there any dimmer switches or other appliances?

My guess is that you will find something else on the circuit draining voltage. Find this device, remove it from the circuit, and your fan should operate normally!

Answer (score 0):

I installed  a new fan that came with a remote which has low, medium and high speed buttons. It also has a pull chain speed selector. It ran slow, very slow and very very slow. I found that the pull chain switch was in slow mode and it took precedent over the remote. Put pull chain switch in high and everything works fine.